# Should we add as a reason for flagging stating the answer in a wrong language?

Tags: feature-request, answers, flags, languages

Sometimes I see on answers that are written in a different language than the language of the site (let's say it's an answer in Portuguese in the English version).

The answers may be correct, but the language is the problem.

I think an option of flagging an answer because is written in the wrong language should be introduced to solve this problem.

What are your opinions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can already flag those as "not an answer" or even "very low quality". Either would do fine. Discussing which flag is "better" for this is rather pointless, the only thing important is to delete these kind of posts as fast as possible.

Posts in a different language should be deleted. It's up to the poster if they want to translate their post into English. An answer in a language different from English is not an answer if posted in an English language site.

There is no need to add another kind of flag, the ones we have work nicely for this scenario.

Comment: The answer my be correct. It doesn't mean it's very low quality.

Comment: It's low quality for the purposes of the site. If our site visitors can't understand it, I'd say it is safe to say it has severe formatting or content issues. An answer not written in English is not an answer if posted on here.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest a not an answer flag here. What if the OP edit their post to translate some minutes after you raise it? A moderator will come and decline your flag. VLQ flags get cleared when a post is OP-edited.

Comment: If it was up to me, I'd kindly ask the OP to translate their answer (or question) to English and see how they respond.

Answer (score 2):

No, we shouldn't at all. There is the very low quality flag for these (I wouldn't suggest not an answer, since it may answer the question). It is also good to leave a comment under the post:

> Please write your answer in English, as [Stack Overflow is an English site.](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676)

It is up to the OP if they would like to translate their post. You know that you did what was correct and you leave the answer to a moderator.

Adding an extra flag won't help. It would, too come to moderators who will delete the post. OP will not be notified once again unless a comment is left.

Comment: "Not an answer" is fine. It *cannot* be an answer because it is not written in English. Moderators do not translate these answers before deleting them.