# How many language-specific Stack Overflow sites are there?

Tags: support, international-sites

I'm not sure how many exists out there. I'm only aware of a few:

| URL | Language |
| --- | --- |
| https://es.stackoverflow.com/ | Spanish |
| https://pt.stackoverflow.com/ | Portuguese |
| https://ru.stackoverflow.com/ | Russian |
| https://ja.stackoverflow.com/ | Japanese |

Are there any others? Where can I find the index?

I wish to know so I can better suggest people to ask on the site that speaks the language in the question.

P.S.: It would be nice to have a proper flag for questions with the "wrong language." Unfortunately, it’s already ironed out in [another Q&A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384387/should-we-add-as-a-reason-for-flagging-stating-the-answer-in-a-wrong-language) with -8. Though, a proper flag might be useful to route the question to moderators or reviewers who actually speaks the asker's language in hope they can tell the asker to check the other site in their native language.

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the question has listed, **there are only 4 localized Stack Overflow sites.**

It's possible to list all by searching for "stackoverflow" (part of the URL, not the site name) on the site switcher.

[image]

However, Stack Exchange has decided to pause further site localization indefinitely. Further reading: [Internationalization 'State of the Stack' - Stack Overflow edition](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20987/106460)